# Table View inside of a normal View Controller using storyboards?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

Is there a way to display a table view inside a normal view controller? Whenever I try to add cells to the table view inside of the normal view controller, nothing appears. I read somewhere that you could link a table view controller to a table view in a view controller, but I can't figure out how to do that using storyboards.

[image]

Comment: You're probably missing an important step, like setting the data source. You can also embed a view controller into another using a container view in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create an IBOutlet for your table view? And is it connected?

After that's done you need to connected the table view's data source and delegate to the view controller.

https://i.imgur.com/Om1Ego4.gif

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add TableView inside normal view without using xib : 
- add tableview inside view controller.
- place tableview cell inside tableview and don't forget to set cell's reuse identifier which will be used in tableview's cellForRowAt method.
- add outlets of tableview in your .swift file
- set delegate and datasource for tableview in storyboard or you can set inside .swift file as yourtableviewname.delegate = self and yourtableviewname.datasource = self
- use tableview's delegate and datasource methods to handle tableview.